# Previous page shown in div, and show last page datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get to the previous page shown in a div. Since I'm opening my pages with ajax in said div, **History Back** method won't work because there's no history saved on the browser. I'm sure that there's something I can do except making a link that opens the older page (that's what I'm currently doing).

This said, since I move from **page_1.php** to **page_2.php** by clicking on a row on datatables, I'm wondering if there's any way I could then **reopen page 1, and show the last page the table was clicked on.**

I don't know if I should post any code, since I'm just asking if there's a method I may be missing, but I will if you guys need to see what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the page variable e.g.

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
var previouspage = 'page_1.php?show='+table.page();
```

Then load previouspage via ajax and on page_1.php load the page

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
table.page( <?php echo $_get['show']; ?> ).draw( false );
```

See: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29